# JQuery UI Autocomplete, Find all words in any order

Tags: javascript, regex, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the JQuery UI Autocomplete javascript program.  I am trying to find all the words in the search box in any order.  That means if I search for "Three One Two"  I want it to be selected if in the database there is a entry called "One Two Three".  It sounds complicated but it really shouldn't be.  Here is my code:

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    max:10, minLength:2, source: function (request, response) {    
        var term = request.term;    
        var list = term.split(" ");
        var arr = [  ]; 
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
            var buf = "/"+list[i]+"/";
            arr.push(buf);
        }
        var rez = [];
        for (var n = 0; n < availableTags.length; n++) { 
             for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
                if(arr[i].test(availableTags[n]){
                    rez.push(abailableTags[n]);
                }
             } 
        }   
        response(rez); 
        return;    
    }    
});
```

It doesn't work yet. If someone could offer me any pointers in this code and perhaps tell me where i have gone wrong it would be awesome!  I can get JQuery Autocomplete to work, but can't get it to match the RegEx search terms.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was working on a similar problem where I wanted to display all matches no matter the order of the keywords. Just to clarify I will show an example:

```
list = ["AK-47 Redline (Minimal Wear)","Statrak AK-47 Redline (Minimal Wear)", "M4A1-S Something (Minimal Wear)"];
```

this is my "database", and if I type "minimal wear" I will get results of everything, but my idea was to be able to type "ak minimal wear", and thus to get suggestions for: `AK-47 Redline (Minimal Wear), Statrak AK-47 Redline (Minimal Wear)` , but instead I was not getting anything because jquery's autocomplete checks if the supplied keywords are indexOf any elements of the list. So in my case I implemented a custom search, where I recursively generate a list of results matching each keyword. Small example:

keywords: ak wear,

list: ["AK-47 Redline (Minimal Wear)","Statrak AK-47 Redline (Minimal Wear)", "M4A1-S Something (Minimal Wear)"]

first I generate a list that contains the first keyword: ak, then I make the recursive call with the newly generated list but this time I check the next keyword, and I continue until I reach the last keyword and simply return the lastly generated list.

Here is the javascript code:

```
var someList = ["seven nine five", "five fifteen twenty", "twenty-five maybe one", "two (five) one"];
$('#name').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var term = request.term;
        var data = handleAutocomplete(term); //your custom handling
        response(data);
    }
});

function recursiveListUpdate(someList, keywords) {
    newList = [];
    someList.forEach(function(element) {
        if (element.toLowerCase().indexOf(keywords[counter].toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            newList.push(decodeURI(element)); //if any %20, etc symbols
        }
    });
    counter++;
    if (counter == keywords.length) {
        return newList;
    }
    return recursiveListUpdate(newList, keywords);
}


function handleAutocomplete(term) {
    var str = term; // get the "keywords"
    var keywordsFromNameInput = str.split(" "); // split them into a list
    counter = 0; // set counter for keywords.lenght
    // recursively get new list that contains the give keywords no matter the order
    return recursiveListUpdate(someList, keywordsFromNameInput);
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8nmcoLds/11/):

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a similar code some days ago.

```
var availableTags = [
    'One Two Three',
    'Four Five Six',
    'Seven Eight Nine Ten'];

$('#tags').autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    search: function (event, ui) {
        $('#wrapper').empty();
    },
    select: function (e, ui) {
        $(this).val(ui.item.name);
        return false;
    },
})
    .data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    matchFound = 0;
    var inp = $("#tags").val().split(" ");
    var items = item.label.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < inp.length; j++) {
            index = items[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(inp[j].toUpperCase());
            if (index > -1) {
                matchFound += 1;
            } else {
                matchFound += 1;
            }
        }
        if (matchFound == inp.length) {
            return $('<div class="element"></div>')
            .data('item.autocomplete', item.label)
            .append('<a href="#">' + item.label + '</a>')
            .appendTo($('#wrapper'));
            break;

        }
    }
};
```

It may help you.
[***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/kr0xo8ds/)

Comment: I don't understand the last function.  Is there a way to get this to update into the search bar?

Comment: The last function _renderItem() is to process final results.